# What esc_html__() does and what is the purpose of its use?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find where the template of my website theme hooks the social icons for sharing, because I want to fill in with some html text before them.
i.e. "share with a friend: 'fb-icon', 'insta-icon', 'youtube-icon', etc".
So, I found this:
`'facebook'   => esc_html__( 'Facebook', 'themes_name' )`
and I can't find nowhere any explanation of what "esc_html__" does.

Thanks.

Comment: this might help [esc_html__() Function Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/)

Answer (score 4):

`esc_html__( string $text, string $domain = 'default' )` is a function used by theme and plugin developers to return HTML code, translated according to the loaded text domain and properly escaped, in order to avoid client-side vulnerabilities (i.e. Cross-site scripting).

Further information about this function can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/)
Further information about Wordpress text domain can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains)
Further information about Cross-site scripting can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)